# Strong separation between packages

Tags: java, package, software-design

I thought about interesting situation in software design. How to hide package (and public class in this package) from package that should not see it?

For example, the three software design layers (UI, BL, DAL). The UI layer should know only the BL layer, and the BL layer should know only the DAL layer.
So the BL package using the DAL package. But how can I prevent from the UI layer to use the DAL layer, without the BL layer or take advantage of the fact that the BL already knew the DAL.

This is only example of what I meant, to prevent from package to see other package without connector-package.

Comment: You could use OSGi for that kind of access rules, but it rarely brings a real benefit.

Comment: I think its needs to be pure software design. We met this situations every day. More than that, its the correct way to design of software.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "pure software" design since OSGi is nothing but software. However, with just plain Java you can't achieve this separation.

Comment: Not "pure software", I said "pure software design". OSGi is a library.

Comment: Agree with @MarkoTopolnik suggestion to use OSGI. Disagree that it doesn't bring a 'real' benefit.

Comment: @agbinfo I meant specifically in a three-tiered architecture. I have worked on several large codebases with three-tiered architecture and never saw any tendency to breach the tier barriers. It simply wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java alone does not enable this kind of separation. As soon as a class needs to be public, its public to *the world*.

I feel with you, as I don't like packages with hundreds of classes, so I like to substructure them into subpackages. Unfortunately this interferes with the only hiding mechanism for classes, using package private classes.

The way one can solve this in practice is usually by separating the code into separate build units (projects, essentially). You can make a separate project for each layer, and only add the layers intended for access as dependecies.

Comment: Theoretical, if I will separating the code into separate build units each layer. The BL will depend on the DAL, so it will receive its public classes that will be shown to the UI, when it will add the BL project. Isn't it?

Comment: But we see this situations every day. The internal package of Android, that each android class use it, but you cant (same thing with the .NET framework if you will open its source). Even C++ libraries like QT. They prevent from you to see and use their classes

Comment: @nrofis Not sure which android package you're referring to, but in *Java* if its on your classpath and its public, you *can* use it. Not counting for classes that actively prevent you from accessing methods at runtime (by SecurityManager, call stack analysis or by simply hinding their constructors etc.). And if you don't add a dependencies dependencies to your build path, you won't see them (e.g. UI project only adds BL.jar, but not DAL.jar).

Comment: Thank you! Separating the Jars limit the public modifier. When project using another project with public class, its not publish the other project classes. Thats what I looked for. Thanks